# questions with a pig latin translator

Tags: javascript, html, string

The code is here on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fizzy/6Ls3D/):

Pig **Latin Translator**

```
<br>
<p style="font-family: verdana; text-align: center;">Enter one word and the program will translate it in to pig latin!</p>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <input class="theinput" id="english" value="Word" title="Enter a single english word"></input>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="translate()" type="button">Translate</button>
    <br>
    <p id="output" style="size: 5; text-align: center; color: red; font-family: monospace;">ordway</p>
</div>
<script>
    function translate() {
        var english = document.getElementById("english").value;
        if ((english.charAt(0) == 'a') || (english.charAt(0) == 'e') || (english.charAt(0) == 'i') || (english.charAt(0) == 'o') || (english.charAt(0) == 'u')) {
            var pigLatin = english + "ay";
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = pigLatin;
        } else {
            alert("in progress');
        }
    }
</script>
```

However it does not set the paragraph to the translated pig latin word when I press the button. what can I do to fix ths?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the console log, you will see

> SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
>   http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
>  Line: 54, Column: 22
>  Source
>   code:
>  alert("in progress');

or something similar (depending on browser).

So there is a simple syntax error. Use

```
alert("in progress");
```

or

```
alert('in progress');
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE:
In chrome "Translate" is a reserved word and the function call to translate() won't work. In IE it will work correctly. Here's a fiddle which works in either browser.. jsfiddle.net/cCdC5/2

==OLD POST==
Firstly there is a typo here.

In your else statement you are using non matching tags. It should be alert("in progress");

Lastly your if statement is looking for a, e, i, o, u as the first letter. 
Your textbox's first letter is "W".

Are you trying to check all values in the input and see if any is a vowel?

**Irrelevant stuff from my original post:** (I didn't know that br tag closing was only in xhtml... jsfiddle prompted me for this error and i figured all html had.)

---

All the "br" tags are not closed, they should be:

```
<br />
```

Comment: "All the "br" tags are not closed, they should be". Nope, this is most likely **HTML** not XHTML or XML.

Comment: The ` /` in `<br />` is redundant in HTML. It only matters in XHTML.

Comment: Oh my bad then.. I guess I have been working with html in .net perspective for too long. Even jsfiddle marked the html in error, so I assumed this was the case with all html.

Comment: No need to be a jerk dude. 
The code works for me as soon as I fixed the alert logic. 
Are you sure you are entering a,e,i,o,u in lowercase because your code only checks lowercase work. 

Which browser are you using.. In chrome "Translate" is a reserved word and the function call to translate() won't work. In IE it will work correctly. 

Here's a fiddle which works in either browser.. http://jsfiddle.net/cCdC5/2/